# Another way to solve the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, quartics

**Problem:** Solve the equation:

$$x^2+23x+23=(x+2)\sqrt{2(x^2+3x+6)}$$

**My attempt**

After I squaring and simplifying, I got the following quartic equation:

$$x^4-32x^3-531x^2-986x-481=0$$

This equation has ugly roots, and it's way too hard to factor out. I've also tried to use [Descartes' solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Descartes'_solution) but failed. How do I solve the quartic equation? (Or is there another way to solve the original equation?)

**Edit:**

The above equation was wrong. This is the correct one:

$$4x^2+23x+23=(x+2)\sqrt{2(x^2+3x+6)}$$

This one seems better, I could just solve by doing the same as above (squaring and use Descartes' solution to solve the quartic equation). But is there a nicer way to solve the equation?

Comment: Why do you believe that the equation has not "ugly" roots?

Comment: @user Both Wolfram Alpha and my calculator give me "ugly" root. I'm not sure if there's a way to solve this quartic equation. If not, I guess squaring the original equation isn't a good way. I haven't been able to think another way to solve the original equation.

Comment: if the last equation you found by squaring gives "ugly" roots, then the initial equation gives "ugly" roots too!

Comment: I am quite sure WA gives the correct roots. And An equation is not obliged to have "nice" roots, is it?

Comment: @user Yes, especially with high degree polynomials. I guess we should try to find another way to solve the original equation.

Comment: The roots of the first equation are a subset of the roots of the second one! You can do nothing with this fact.

Comment: @user Yep. This may be one of the reason makes the equation very hard to solve, and I think there's no way to solve the problem (somehow).

Comment: There is a way - the numerical solution!

Comment: @user Agree, though it's not really the best way (probably)!

Comment: There is no reason to ever assume a quartic will have a nice root.  If the rational root theorem fails then you probably will not have any nice easy ways to solve it.  This is *not* surprising.  This in *normal*.

Comment: @fleablood OK Thanks!

Comment: With help of a CAS, after squaring, the quartic equation from the new equation factors into $$(2x^2+14x+13)( 7x^2+36x+37) = 0$$ Two of the roots $-\frac{\sqrt{65}+18}{7}$, $\frac{\sqrt{23}-7}{2}$ solves the original equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do but solve the quartic numerically – there's no way to simplify the exact expressions. All the roots are real, so we check whether each root satisfies the original equation, and we find that three do:
$$x=-10.392800\dots$$
$$x=-0.897551\dots$$
$$x=44.450403\dots$$

Comment: Seems like we need another way to approach the solution to the original equation.

Comment: @windowsprime No. There is no other way. This _is_ the solution.

Comment: Actually $x = -1.160051 \ldots$ is not a solution of the original equation: it gives the wrong sign for the square root.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Edited.